# Django- "python manage.py runserver" not working

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

Hi im new to django and i cant get my web server running. First of all i viewed several of other threads and ive been searching for a solution for 4 hours and i couldn't find any help.

So this is what ive done:

- Installed django using the following "pip install django"
- Created a project using "django-admin startproject DjangoProject"
- Went into the directory using "cd DjangoProject"
- Inputted "python manage.py runserver" into the console and the console doesn't display anything.

So ive tried several of methods to solve this issue and have even set up environmental variables

- C:\Python37\scripts
- C:\Python37

After setting up environmental variables when i input "python -m django --version" or "python manage.py runserver" i receive an output of "'python' is not recognised as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

I think i haven't set up my environmental variables properly

Have i set up my environmental variables properly? Or have i done something else wrong, I can't seem to figure out the problem. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `python` is not recognized. If you type just `python` into your terminal do you get an error or does it open the REPL? What happens if you use `python3`?

Comment: it should be 'C:\Python37\Scripts' with capital `S` for scipts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you disagree with the environment variable. It has two ways of solving it.

1- You can reinstall python, in the wizard you must check the option:

"add python to environment variables".

2- the other way would be to manually agree on the environment variables, for this you create a new environment variable with the name "Path" and add the following as value:

```
% USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Python\Python37\
C:\Python\Python37\Scripts\
```

Comment: Thanks, when i installed python i didnt check the "Add Python to variable environment" button, so i modified the file and added it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the step where you have already created and activated your virtual environment already activated

virtualenv name

source name/bin/activate